# What Should i do to get PyQt4 working on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.10, pyqt

Installed python-qt4 and pyqt4-dev-tools packages on ubuntu

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 but the PyQt4.QtGui module requires API v7.1
```

What Should i do to get PyQt4 working?

Comment: ah, this has burned my fingers for too long.

Comment: So did u get it working finally?